Can I rewind from a NavigationStack X number of Views?
If I'm using NavigationStack and somewhere in the fourth or fifth view I need to rewind and send the user back three or four views, is there a way to do that programmatically?
I realize I can set an environment variable that on appear dismisses screens sending the user back a few views, but that sounds kludgy.
struct MainMenu: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack{
                List{
                    NavigationLink {
                        InvoiceMenu()
                    } label: {
                        MenuButton(choice: "invoice")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


You do programatic navigation by using the navigation stack's path input, which is bound to an array. The array controls which items in the navigation stack are presented. E.g. if I had:
@State var array = [Int]()
NavigationStack(path: $array) { items }

You could append to the array to add an item on the navigation stack, and then call the .removeLast() method on the array 4 times to go back 4 screens.
Paul explain these topics masterfully on YouTube:

Handling navigation the smart way with navigationDestination()
Programmatic navigation with NavigationStack

